# How to calculate distance from camera to target? (in Python)

Tags: python-3.x, distance, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the distance between the camera and the ground using this equation.

Distance = D

Camera Height = CH (meters)

Camera Angle = CA

D = CH/cos(CA)

So in code I am doing this to calculate the distance

```
def findDistance(CH, CA):
    return CH / math.cos(CA)

#for test
cameraHight = 1.2 #In meter
cameraAngle = 65   #Degress angle
estimatedDistance = findDistance(cameraHight, cameraAngle)
print(estimatedDistance)
```

Which then gives me this -2.1335083711460943. I dont think the answer should be negative should it. The distance to the target is about right but its not a negative 2 meters.

Any suggestions on how to better do this or what I am doing wrong will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you think the answer shouldn't be negative? You're using cos() with can return negative values.  If you want the answer to be positive use the absolute value of CH/cos(CA).

Comment: Should I always take the absolute value of this? If so why? I really want to understand this

Comment: Its math, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well cos(65 degree) = 0.42261826174, cos(65 radians) = -0.56245385123.

According to documentation:

```
math.cos(x)
Return the cosine of x radians.
```

You need to convert your degrees to radians first.

```
cameraAngle = 65
cameraRadians = math.radians(cameraAngle)
```

And then use cameraRadians in your calculation, instead of cameraAngle.

In Full:

```
def findDistance(CH, CA):
    return CH / math.cos(CA)

#for test
cameraHight = 1.2 #In meter
cameraAngle = 65   #Degress angle
cameraRadians = math.radians(cameraAngle) #convert degrees to radians
estimatedDistance = findDistance(cameraHight, cameraRadians)
print(estimatedDistance)
```

Answer (score 1):

cos function takes argument in radians and not degrees.

Change

```
return CH / math.cos(CA)
```

to

```
return CH / math.cos(math.radians(CA))
```